# Best way to represent raw bytes in a std::vector?

Tags: c++, sockets, stl, buffer, stdvector

I'm working with the ZeroMQ library which uses `void *` to represent blocks of arbitrary binary data.  However I'd like to use `std::vector` to copy and move these blocks around.  What is the preferred, idiomatic way to make a `std::vector` representing raw bytes?  I'm currently using a `std::vector<unsigned char>` but I want to make sure my code makes sense to other people.

Comment: `unsigned char` is OK. If you want to emphasize the octet part, you can also use `uint8_t`.

Comment: I would `typedef uint8_t byte;`, or maybe even make a class that you can't really do anything with. (no adding bytes togeather)

Comment: Does ZeroMQ itself specify anywhere whether it reads the data "as a char" or "as an unsigned char"? If not then unsigned char should be fine. If it specifies `char` then you might want to use that just to emphasise that you're supplying what the library expects. It shouldn't make any difference anyway.

Comment: ZeroMQ is a message passing library so it never does anything with the data besides copying and sending on the wire.  So I think it doesn't matter...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either

```
std::vector<unsigned char>
```

or

```
#include <cstdint>

std::vector<std::uint8_t>
```

both seem fine to me.

Comment: `uint8_t` won't exist on a system that doesn't have 8-bit bytes. `uint_least8_t` might be a better choice, but `unsigned char` is the best choice.

Comment: This solution seems to be widely used for storing raw data. For me it is unclear why to use "uint8_t" and not "int8_t" - does anybody know the advantage? Java does only has signed data types, so why to use unsigned int in c++?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the nature of your data, `unsigned char` is the smallest chunk of bits that you can represent without getting messy. Therefore it is a common type for any kind of arbitrary memory block.

So your vector looks perfectly fine the way it is.